# create index in mongodb using powershell

Tags: powershell, mongodb-.net-driver

*** EDITED ***
could someone please help me creating an index in mongodb using powershell?

I am following this [create index using c# driver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-csharp/e5j7mP3qrWg)

this is my code:

```
$keys = IndexKeys.Ascending("Message Subject", "Job Result").Descending("Time Stamp")
$options = new-object MongoDB.Driver.IndexOptionsDocument
$options.SetUnique(true)
$notificationCollectionByDate.CreateIndex(keys, options)
```

I got the following errors

> Method invocation failed because [MongoDB.Driver.IndexOptionsDocument]
>   doesn't contain a method named 'SetUnique'.
>
> The term 'IndexKeys.Ascending' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and tr y again.

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just like the keys.  Don't create a document if you are using the helpers.

`$options = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.IndexOptions]::SetUnique(true)`

Comment: thanks Craig, no it doesn't work I don't know why it is not recognising any method from IndexKeys either...

Comment: Well, that's a different problem than the one you posted.  You can use the fully qualified name (MongoDB.Driver.Builders).  In addition, you seem to be invoking static methods incorrectly( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347632.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

thanks Craig you gave me the clue to get the answer:

this is the solution:

```
$keys = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.IndexKeys]
$keys = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.IndexKeys]::Ascending("Message Subject", "Job Result")
$keys = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.IndexKeys]::Descending("Time Stamp")
$options = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.IndexOptions]::SetUnique($true)
$options = [MongoDB.Driver.Builders.IndexOptions]::SetDropDups($true)
$notificationCollectionByDate.CreateIndex($keys, $options)
```